# Why in nitration of benzene we use concentrated sulfuric and nitric acid and not the dilute version of it?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

Is there any different if we use the dilute version? Most experiment I read in book use conc. acid but didn't explain why.

Comment: Because dilute acids won't work, as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

The first reaction happens in the mixture $\ce{HNO_3 + H_2SO_4}$ : $$\ce{HNO_3 + 2 H_2SO_4 -> NO_2^+  +  2 HSO_4^-  +  H_3O^+}$$
Then benzene reacts with $\ce{NO_2^+}$.
But water must be absent, because, if there is the smallest amount of water molecules, the ion $\ce{NO_2^+}$ would immediately be destroyed. It would quickly react according to : $$\ce{NO_2^+  + 2 H_2O  -> HNO_3  +  H_3O^+ }$$ So this would prevent the reaction with benzene.

Comment: You're vastly overstating water interference. Even "100 %" H2SO4 has a bit of water due to self condensation, and I mean unprotonated H2O.